# SQL performance issue on grouping - time out

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, grouping

I have some data - with ContactID - Start datetime and End datetime columns.
Source looks like this:

```
ContactID | A_DTStart        | A_DTEnd
      123 | 2014-03-04 23:43 | 2014-03-05 02:01
      121 | 2014-02-03 12:34 | 2014-02-03 14:44
      ...
```

I try to group them - but with only 115 records - it takes already around 38 seconds to run the query.

```
With
  AT1 As (Select
      EventLogUnpvt.ContactID,
      DateAdd(minute, -1 * IsNull(MasterLesson.DTstart, 0),
      Convert(date,EventLog.EventDate) +
      Convert(datetime,Convert(time,LandingLog.OffBlocks))) As A_DTstart,
      DateAdd(day, Case
        When
        (Convert(float,Convert(datetime,Convert(time,LandingLog.OffBlocks))) >
        Convert(float,Convert(datetime,Convert(time,LandingLog.OnBlocks)))) Then
        1 Else 0
      End, DateAdd(minute, IsNull(MasterLesson.DTend, 0),
      Convert(date,EventLog.EventDate) +
      Convert(datetime,Convert(time,LandingLog.OnBlocks)))) As A_DTend
    From
      LandingLog Inner Join
      EventLog On LandingLog.EventLogID = EventLog.ID Inner Join
      StudentLesson On EventLog.StudentLessonID = StudentLesson.StudentLessonID
      Inner Join
      MasterLesson On MasterLesson.ID = StudentLesson.LessonID Inner Join
      EventLogUnpvt On EventLogUnpvt.ID = EventLog.ID
    Where
      EventLog.EventDate > GetDate() - 2),
  a As (Select
      a.*,
      Row_Number() Over (Partition By a.ContactID Order By a.A_DTstart) As seqnum
    From
      AT1 a),
  ate As (Select
      a.ContactID,
      a.A_DTstart,
      a.A_DTend,
      a.seqnum,
      1 As grp,
      a.A_DTstart As grp_start
    From
      a
    Where
      a.seqnum = 1
    Union All
    Select
      a.ContactID,
      a.A_DTstart,
      a.A_DTend,
      a.seqnum,
      (Case When a.A_DTstart - ate.grp_start <= 14.0 / 24 Then ate.grp
        Else ate.grp + 1 End),
      (Case When a.A_DTstart - ate.grp_start <= 14.0 / 24 Then ate.grp_start
        Else a.A_DTstart End)
    From
      ate Join
      a On ate.ContactID = a.ContactID And ate.seqnum = a.seqnum - 1)
Select
  ate.*
From
  ate
```

well... issue is - that I need to run it over 1000+ records. And there I get a timeout.

Is there another approach to this query?

Comment: Do you have any indexes in your tables?

Comment: Maybe there is another more efficient way to write this.  It would help if you describe what the query is supposed to do and provide sample and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This is a formatted comment.  You have this:

```
Case
    When
    (Convert(float,Convert(datetime,Convert(time,LandingLog.OffBlocks))) >
    Convert(float,Convert(datetime,Convert(time,LandingLog.OnBlocks)))) Then
    1 Else 0
```

Is there any reason it can't be simplified to this?

```
Case When LandingLog.OffBlocks > LandingLog.OnBlocks Then 1 Else 0
```

If so, that will save you processing time.

Generally speaking, your entire query might be a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  It's hard to say though because it's not clear what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason.  The original is comparing times not the full `datetime` value.

Comment: If that was the objective, he still used 3 converts to do so when 1 was enough.

Comment: yes - there is a reason why I used the double convert - because some users (who will modify the data...) can not garantee that they use the correct date-part. So they write OnBlocks (2014-03-02 01:32) < OffBlocks (2014-03-02 23:12)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the execution plan tools in sql management studio to help hunt down the slow parts. Right click in a query window and you'll have options to display the estimated plan and the actual plan. That will most often help you run down just which part is a problem.

The number of results is only a very small factor in how long a query takes to process and usually only comes down to affecting how fast it can transfer from the server.

The number of records that SQL Server must process is usually the culprit. If you are joining to records via columns that are not indexed and those source tables are big, it will be slow. Index those columns if this report is of any importance. I've seen many people get all kinds of worried about how indexes will affect insert/update/delete and forget that Read is the most common operation we perform.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now - first I create a new table - add all data into it from first two CTE.
Than I run from this table the last query...
all together takes now less than 5 sec. for more than 5000 records.